# Camel way to filter HTTP headers on CXF SOAP messages

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, camel-cxf

I have built a Camel application that consumes from Kafka, calls a SOAP service and produces to Kafka.

Because of **Camels automatic header transport** between protocols (very useful), there were quite some **unneeded message headers** on Kafka messages and SOAP requests as well. Since I don't want to remove them from the Camel Exchange, I used Camels `HeaderFilterStrategy` to remove them on outgoing messages only.

I extended Camels `KafkaHeaderFilterStrategy` to filter the message headers on produced Kafka messages. I tried to do the same with `CxfHeaderFilterStrategy` but that seems to filter only the SOAP headers while my SOAP requests contained all Kafka headers as HTTP headers.

Therefore I built a **CXF out interceptor** that filters the Map of `Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS`.

That works well, but I wonder **if there is a "Camel way" to filter the HTTP headers of CXF SOAP messages**.